# How to pass int Value from one view controller to next in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to send the myNumber values to the next controller in iphone app  as normaaly do for NSString i am doing like this but it is not working

```
  int mynumber=100;
  NextViewController*targetController=[[NextViewController alloc]init];
  targetController.mynumber=mynumber;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController animated:YES];
```

NextViewController

```
  int mynumber;
```

Implementation NextViewController

```
  int mydata=mynumber;
```

Comment: Could you post the declaration of `NextViewController` `mynumber` property.

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting property for mynumber in viewController you are passing value to?

Comment: And can you tell us what is going on ? Is there a warning, an error, a crash ?

Comment: I am adding like this int myNumber in nextViewController only

Comment: @KiranAftab please tell your property declaration for myNumber

Comment: @saadnib i have not set property how to set it

Comment: can you please paste code of your NextViewController.h ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you `NextViewController.h` file declare a `property` of type `int` with var name `mynumber` like this -

```
NextViewController.h

@property (nonatomic) int mynumber;
```

then `synthesize` it in `NextViewController.m`

```
NextViewController.m

@synthesize mynumber;
```

now you can `assign` it as you are doing;

Answer (score 2):

In `NextViewController` make property of integer and synthesize it.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger mynumber; 

@synthesize mynumber;
```

then

```
int mynumber=100;
NextViewController *targetController=[[NextViewController alloc]init];
targetController.mynumber=mynumber;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property in NextViewController.h first:

```
@property NSInteger mynumber;
```

And in NextViewController.m:

```
@synthesize mynumber;
```

Your code will work after these steps.

Answer (score 0):

@property NSInteger mynumber;

And in NextViewController.m:

@synthesize mynumber;

work very good

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a **thank you** or a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score -2):

I your `AppDelegate.m` create `int dataString;` as a global variable. Now use it to pass data from one View to another by adding your code to your firstView like `int FirstViewData = dataString;` Now Call it in your Second View similarly.

Comment: may i declare this without any property

Comment: if i am doing it withour propery it is saying assinging unknown if i am simple using int number in appDelegate

Comment: The application delegate is for data and services that have broad application-wide and/or application-specific applicability. Passing a value from one view controller to another, especially when they have a direct relationship to each other, is just not even close to appropriate to put in the app delegate.

Comment: @TejeshwarGill Good grief... are you serious? If you're using the appDelegate in this way you really need to rethink you app design.