# Don't succeed to pass double value from one controller to another

Tags: controller, double, exchange-server, viewcontroller

I try to follow some pages like this : [How to pass int Value from one view controller to next in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191767/how-to-pass-int-value-from-one-view-controller-to-next-in-iphone-app) in order to pass a double value (called calories) from one controller (CalViewController) to another (DrinksViewController).

Here what is at the end my CalViewController.m :

```
- (IBAction)suite:(id)sender {
{
    DrinksViewController *targetController=[[DrinksViewController alloc]init];
    targetController.calories=calories;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Here what is in my DrinksViewController.h :

```
@interface DrinksViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *drinksCollectionView;
@property (nonatomic) double calories;

@end
```

And here is my DrinksViewController.m :

```
@implementation DrinksViewController

@synthesize calories;
double test=calories;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

self = [super initWithNibName:@"DestinationViewController" bundle:nil];
if (self) {
    calories = [calories copy];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[super viewDidLoad];
self.calories.text = calories;
}
```

Many things are not recognized by xCode and I don't succeed to see what.

Thanks for your help

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

I've succeed with an stackoverflow answer : 
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

In the "Passing Data Forward using Segue's" part.

Perfect and not too complicated with a segue.